# Как убрать отступы Layout'а

Tags: android, android-layout

Всем привет. В своем проекте добавляю в main.xml два layout'а (relative layout и table layout),а вокруг них появляются отступы, которые мне не нужны. Как их убрать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: XML-разметку покажите. Возможно, во внешнем Layout у вас Padding стоит

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался))дело в Padding

Answer (score 3):

За отступы от границ экрана отвечает свойство компонента padding. Установите padding у главного layout'a в 0:

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Лучшим решением, чем `android:padding="0dp"`, будет вовсе удалить строку с ненужным паддингом. Эффект будет точно такой же, зато устройству не придется тратить ресурсы на абсолютно бесполезный парсинг и расчеты.

Comment: Благодарю. Очень полезная информация для меня!